# Cmake "Could not create symbolic link"

Tags: cmake

Hello i am trying to build a project with cmake but i get following error

```
CMake Error at tests/CMakeLists.txt:116 (message):
  Could not create symbolic link for:
  C:/CePlusPlus/ssl_normal/tests/data_files --> Invalid switch -
  "CePlusPlus".

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/CePlusPlus/ssl_normal-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should post the part of your CMakeLists.txt giving this error... otherwise, we won't be able to help :)

Comment: Given message is output by CMake `message()` command. Without code we may only guess why the project do that. Looks like the project creates link manually in Unix-like way, but this is Windows, which interprets path delimiter `/` as switch.

Comment: Tsyvarev was right, there was test for Unix systems so i disabled testing and it is working now. Thank you